# Passing 'self' issue in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

Guys i wrote a utility function in a Utility class

```
func showAlert(vc: UIViewController) {
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(defaultAction)

        vc.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

if i call this function from currentViewController it gives error like this

[image]

Comment: Try creating an instance of your AppUtil class `AppUtil().showAlert()`

Comment: declare show alert as `static func showAlert(...` or `class func showAlert(...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `AppUtil` already initialized? If not you need to call `AppUtil()` or initialize it in a variable or whatever.